# TimerTask and Thread

Tags: java, groovy

What's the difference between TimerTask and Thread in Java and Groovy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both TimerTask and Thread execute asynchronously, but TimerTask is scheduled to execute at fixed intervals while Thread is not. A Thread is a fairly low-level primitive for parallel execution in a shared virtual address space, and it runs whenever it is on the run queue and gets a turn to run; a TimerTask is only eligible to run at the fixed intervals at which it was scheduled to run.

Answer (score 3):

TimerTask and Thread behave identically whether you run them using Groovy or Java.

TimerTask facilitates execution of one-time or recurring tasks using a Timer. TimerTask has really got nothing to do with Threads, apart from the fact that the Timer will execute these tasks in a background thread (though this could be considered an implementation detail of the Timer class).

Thread on the other hand, is a low-level class for doing parallel execution of *anything* in a separate thread, and doesn't provide any timing or job-scheduling functionality.